# AsyncTask finishes, but Activity UI not updated for 20+ seconds

Tags: java, android

I have an AsyncTask for querying my database, but it can take 20+ seconds for the UI to update. At first I thought it was slow DB queries, but after putting in some debug statements, it turns out that everything is actually done quite quickly. The last instruction in onPostExecute completes, and then 20+ seconds later the UI finally updates. This happens on a phone running Android 9 Pie, on earlier versions it's considerably faster. Why would that be? What could be going on?
EDIT: On a phone running Android 7, it takes ~2 seconds.

```
void callBackgroundQuery(String query){
    backgroundQuery BQ = new backgroundQuery(this);
    BQ.execute(query);
}

private class backgroundQuery extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private ReadingActivity mReadingActivity;

    public backgroundQuery(ReadingActivity ra){
        mReadingActivity = ra;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... query) {
        System.out.println("Getting DB Instance");
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
        System.out.println("Querying DB");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query[0],null);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String chap, verse, text;
        int bookNum;
        System.out.println("Moving to first and parsing lines");
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            bookNum = c.getInt(0);
            chap = c.getString(1);
            verse = c.getString(2);
            text = c.getString(3);
            String completeVerse = getAbbreviation(bookNum) + " " + chap + ":" + verse + " " + text;
            builder.append(completeVerse).append("\n");
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished parsing, starting builder.toString()");
        String completeText = builder.toString();
        System.out.println("Finished building string, returning and setting text");
        return completeText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Setting text");
        mTextView.setText(result);
        System.out.println("Setting scroll");
        mReadingActivity.setScroll();
        // This outputs, and 20+ seconds later the TextView displays the text
        System.out.println("Finished setting scroll");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your argument for doInbackground is a String, but you're passing (or trying to pass) an array; query[0]. Is that intentional?

Comment: @zuko `donInBackground` excepts vararg generic type, in this case a `String` - `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` & `protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params)`

Comment: If the `AsyncTask` completes, then it is not the problem.  How much text are you trying to set in the text view? If it is a lot it may have exposed some problems, due to extra calculations in Android 9, of setting large amounts of text. You should use the Android Profiler to check what's blocking the call stack on the main thread.

Comment: Are you possibly blocking the UI thread somewhere else? Try modifying `onPostExecute` to only set a small string like "Done" to see that is the problem as suggested by @MarkKeen.

Comment: It can be a massive amount of text, but this problem only occurs on Android 9. On earlier versions it takes only 2-3 seconds for the text to display. On Android 9 it's 20+.

Comment: @MarkKeen If I do the same query but set the text to simply "Done", it finishes in a fraction of a second. So I guess it's an issue with Android 9 setText. Can you think of any workarounds?

Comment: I'd think that a better approach would be to only load the text you would need to fill the screen and use a paging mechanism - treating it like a book, rather than endless scrolling.  If it is taking 20+ seconds it must be a huge amount of chars.  If you could narrow down, using the Android Profiler, what is causing the block on the UI by method tracing `setText` then it may reveal more options or a simple workaround, rather than redesign. Although IMHO pagination (lazy loading) is a better design.

Comment: Just found this new Android 9 api, might be of help - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/PrecomputedText - you would in essence compute all text measuements in your async task and return a `PrecomputedText` object back - note you would require specific implementation for Android 9 only if you used this.

Comment: @MarkKeen cheers for that reminder!

Comment: Just break into the debugger during that 20 second period and see what the main thread's call stack looks like.

Comment: @MarkKeen PrecomputedText did the trick! Thank you so much for your help! Now how do I choose a comment as the answer...? Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: Glad it works for your needs. I'd post your solution, with final code, as an answer - and mark it as correct so that others can may benefit from it.   I might delve deeper into this issue myself to see what's causing the lag (probably measuring text i'd imagine) as I'm intrigued what's changed in API revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the Android Pie slow setText problem, I used PrecomputedText as per the suggestion in the comments. I made separate AsyncTask classes for use depending on the SDK version. I don't know if there's a better way to handle that part, but the real solution to my question is answered by using PrecomputedText in Android 9.

```
void callBackgroundQuery(String query){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28){
        backgroundQueryAPI28 BQ = new backgroundQueryAPI28(this);
        BQ.execute(query);
    } else {
        backgroundQuery BQ = new backgroundQuery(this);
        BQ.execute(query);
    }
}

private class backgroundQueryAPI28 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, PrecomputedText>{
    private ReadingActivity mReadingActivity;

    final PrecomputedText.Params params = mTextView.getTextMetricsParams();
    final Reference textViewRef = new WeakReference<>(mTextView);

    public backgroundQueryAPI28(ReadingActivity ra){
        mReadingActivity = ra;
    }

    @Override
    protected PrecomputedText doInBackground(String... query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query[0],null);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String chap, verse, text;
        int bookNum;
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            bookNum = c.getInt(0);
            chap = c.getString(1);
            verse = c.getString(2);
            text = c.getString(3);
            String completeVerse = getAbbreviation(bookNum) + " " + chap + ":" + verse + " " + text;
            builder.append(completeVerse).append("\n");
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        String allText = builder.toString();
        final PrecomputedText precomputedText = PrecomputedText.create(allText, params);
        return precomputedText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PrecomputedText result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTextView.setText(result);
        mReadingActivity.setScroll();
    }
}

private class backgroundQuery extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private ReadingActivity mReadingActivity;

    public backgroundQuery(ReadingActivity ra){
        mReadingActivity = ra;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query[0],null);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String chap, verse, text;
        int bookNum;
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            bookNum = c.getInt(0);
            chap = c.getString(1);
            verse = c.getString(2);
            text = c.getString(3);
            String completeVerse = getAbbreviation(bookNum) + " " + chap + ":" + verse + " " + text;
            builder.append(completeVerse).append("\n");
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        String allText = builder.toString();
        return allText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTextView.setText(result);
        mReadingActivity.setScroll();
    }
}
```